# android getview of adapter class not called as ArrayList.size()

Tags: android, android-adapter

hello all i have made one adpter class in that   `listCountry.size();` in **getcount** shows me ***the actual size that is of 500***. But the **getview** call o***nly for 11 time***

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmop;
        private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
        private Activity activity;

        public ImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listCountry) {
            super();

            // this.listCountry = listCountry;
            this.listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.listCountry = listCountry;

            this.activity = activity;
            System.out.println("this is contry name " + this.listCountry);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            System.out.println("len " + listCountry.size());// this shows 500
            return listCountry.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return listCountry.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder view;
            LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            if (convertView == null) {
                System.out.println(arg0+" this is from Adpter "+listCountry.get(arg0) );// this shows only first 11
                view = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, null);

                // Typeface typeface =
                // Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/DroidSerif.ttf");

                view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.image);
                view.pb = (ProgressBar) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

                // d.execute("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");

                // view.imgViewFlag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_default);
                convertView.setTag(view);

            } else {
                view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            try {
                // view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
                // view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));
                //DownloadImageTask d = new DownloadImageTask(view.imgViewFlag);
            //  d.execute(listCountry.get(arg0));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("this is error " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: ListView recycles views. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works

Comment: plz explain it in detail

Comment: As you are using recycle view `convertView` hence `getView()` called only visible rows count on your screen. + another reference view.

Comment: mean? not able to understand

Comment: how did you know getView method is call only 11 times?it calls only when new view required to display

Comment: Suppose there is space of 10 items to display. `getView()` is called 10 times. an upon scroll the views are recycled. Note visible views are not recycled

Comment: see my updated System.out.println(arg0+" this is from Adpter "+listCountry.get(arg0) );// this shows only first 11 this is in getview

Comment: @Pragna bcoz at first only 11 rows are displayed. tried looking at the log by scrolling so that one row goes off screen. You will know what i meant by recycling

Comment: Ok, remove if - else condition and only use code inside of if condition part. Now your `getView()` will be called size of data array..

Comment: @raghu.. my problem is that i am downloading img ok? in getview.. so prob is that i am getting overlap the imag by another 11 again  by another 11 mean each time only loads 11  images

Comment: @Pragna use lazy loading with caching. Downlaod the sample @ http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @Pragna - Try my above comment it will solve your problem.

Comment: removing if else not working...:(

Answer (score 0):

It will only populate the list with the items that can fit your screen size and are visible to you. if you are using large images then you can feel the lag caused by this method

Comment: my current problem is that i am getting only 11 img.. after that another 11... so my current images are overlapping by another 11 images

Comment: please be a little clear in your problem. I am not able to understand it